# What would be an appropriate opposite of "exceed"?

Tags: single-word-requests

*Exceed* is commonly used, but when I found myself wanting to use the opposite I couldn't really find a single word that would do it.

*fall short of* and *inadequate* are a little off.
How about *deceed*?

Comment: I'm a user and proponent of *deceed*, so I recommend it in all cases. Neologisms can hardly be bad if they're both obvious and genuinely useful. I'm only posting this as a comment because this is something of a stylistic question, and if you're looking for more common alternatives, the other answers have them.

Comment: I'm using *deceed* in a engineering context because I don't like the sad emotion connotation of the alternatives. *We collect amplitude readings exceeding 17 dBm and take the average of those exceeding values.* Noise amplitude readings LESS than the annoying threshold should not be called *underwhelming*!

Comment: I would have said "fall short of" – I don't see why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a handful of options depending on context:

> They have exceeded expectations
>
> They have missed expectations
>
> They have eluded expectations

---

> You have exceeded the limit
>
> You are under the limit
>
> You are beneath the limit

---

> Profits exceed costs
>
> Costs exceed profits
>
> Profits are below costs
>
> Profits did not meet costs

Comment: I particularly like the `cost:profit` example and hadn't thought of inverting the relationship of *what* was being exceeded, i.e. "Expectations exceeded his capabilities."

Comment: "*Falling below*" would be fitting for this (6 year old) list.

Answer (score 6):

Latin roots: exceed or *excessus* (surpass, go above, go beyond, go over, top, beat).

Latin roots: recede or *recedere* (move away, retreat, withdraw, drawback, draw away).

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is one of the cases where the context helps a bit to choose the correct expression. In evaluations it often says "below expectation / meets expectation / exceeds expectation (choose one)".

In a sentence, I'd be inclined to use:

> Tom has exceeded our expectations, but Jim has fallen behind.

Comment: It seems a bit of a mixed comparison. I would be inclined to give each man his own sentence.

Answer (score 4):

*Underwhelm* is one of my favorites as it is so thoroughly an antonym of overwhelm, which could take the place of exceeded expectations.

If you need to use *expectations* I would have to default to longer expressions like *did not satisfy*, *fell short*. *Exceed*, coming from *excess*, has no direct-sounding antonym that carries its connotation that feels natural to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to be glib and Jim was know to be underwhelming, you could say that Jim *met* your expectations. To be followed up with, *and that is why we have decided to terminate his service with our company*.

Answer (score 3):

You might go with "underperformed".