# "To go below a minimum numeric requirement": opposite of "exceed"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

Often for configuration settings we have minimum and maximum numeric values.  An error message might report that one has *exceeded* the maximum value.  But it seems very wrong to report that one *exceeded* the minimum value.  Is there an equivalent to *exceeded* that means *went below*?

[What would be an appropriate opposite of "exceed"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18597/what-would-be-an-appropriate-opposite-of-exceed) is related, but the answers did not seem to apply well to numeric values.

Comment: As the tag indicates, I'm hoping for a one-word answer.  Perhaps I should have been explicit in the question.

Comment: In the workplace, I've seen forms that had three options: (a) met standards; (b) exceeded standards; and (c) did not meet (or, failed to meet) standards. I'm not saying that there's _not_ a single word (that's why this is just a comment), but I do think it's worth pointing out that there is precedent for using "does not meet," so that may be the most straightforward way to express the sentiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an error message, one might

- fall short of
- not reach/attain
- fail to reach
- fall below

a minimum value.

For a single word, you could say the minimum value is *unattained,* but that's an awkward way of putting things.

Answer (score 3):

You could use *undershoot* or *under deliver*.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions are:

- *To fall below*
- *To deceed*

Comment: In my head I tried things like deceeded, underseeded, receeded, ... :)

Comment: googling for "deceed" is interesting.

Comment: I've removed the last paragraph because coming up with neologisms is not the purpose of single-word requests, and not a good use of the SE format anyway. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise. Coining new words is the opposite of that; it solicits debate, arguments, polling, and extended discussion. In fact, even *deceed* is a questionable choice, and I would expect it to be clearly labeled as such.

Answer (score 2):

The term **[underrange](http://www3.emersonprocess.com/Systems/Support/bol113/extfile/b_theory/html/overrangeandunderrangedetection.htm)** is apparently used. Its obverse is **overrange**.

It doesn't appear to be very common though.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought was 'outside the limit', but when I googled it, I found examples that went 'beyond the limit'.

My next thought was 'under the limit'.

[What is Under the Limit?](http://www.carrsq.qut.edu.au/utl/)

[Outside the tolerance](http://www.ipcorporation.in/tolerance_of_flanges.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with "underperform".

Though it doesn't mean it's just below the expected aim. Curious to know if there's such a word for this particular case.