# An alternative to "Exceed" when falling below a lower limit

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to describe conditions falling below a lower limit. In this case there is a minimum temperature limit, and the actual temperature has fallen below this limit. I am drawn to use the work *exceed*, but I feel this implies the value is greater than the limit.

For Example, what is an alternative to *exceeds* in this sentence:

"The temperature *exceeds* the minimum temperature."

Comment: You may simply say that the temperature "is under" the minimum temperature (or that it is under the minimum threshold).

Comment: You used the correct answer in the title of the question. I don't think you can do any better than **fall below**: _The temperature fell below the minimum temperature_. As for _exceed_, it would only make logical sense with the following horrible construction (which needless to say I don't recommend): _The coldness exceeds the maximum coldness_.

Comment: One might say "fails the lower limit".

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18597/what-would-be-an-appropriate-opposite-of-exceed and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97324/antonym-for-exceed. The answers there suggest "fall below" is the correct usage.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Job well done. Hurry up, you have 178 rep points to go. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:  "Yesterday, the temperature for Brrr, Minnesota, ***dropped below*** its historic minimum."  Or, "***dropped below*** its average minimum for the past N years."

That's two words and you asked for one word.  Sorry.  Even if you use *recede*, you will have to say:  "Temperature for Brrr receded below its ......" as  BleepBlopOverflow's answer said.

You are right in thinking that *Exceeded the minimum* is going to be interpreted as that the temperature was above the minimum.  Possibly you could make an argument the other way, but it would be a hard sell. If you want clarity, don't say "exceeded the minimum" when you mean "below the minimum".

[Exceed](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=exceed):

> be greater in number or size than (a quantity, number, or other
>   measurable thing).  "production costs have exceeded $60,000"
>
> •go beyond what is allowed or stipulated by (a set limit, especially
>   of one's authority).  "the Tribunal's decision clearly exceeds its
>   powers under the statute"
>
> synonyms: be more than, be greater than, be over, go beyond,
>   overreach, top  "the cost will exceed $400"
>
> •be better than; surpass. "catalog sales have exceeded expectations"

Comment: _Passed_ is one word, actually. I'd use "dropped below," of course. "Made hay of the lower limit" might be good too. Problem is, "exceed" is associated with forward and upward motion.

Comment: I like dropped below, or will drop below. Or even as Dan Romik points out fall below. As pointed out this isn't a single-word but it does help me describe what is happening in an unambiguous way.

Answer (score 2):

> **Undershoot**
>   1:  to shoot short of or below (a target) - [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undershoot)

*The temperature **undershoots** the minimum temperature.*

This term is best used in the context of a [control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_system) - i.e. in a system intended to maintain a temperature range, where failure to do so led to excessive cooling.

Comment: Has anyone ever seen a document that reports failure of a lower temperature limit as undershoot?  In technical documentation under and overshoot describe dynamics.  While this transient may indeed fail a limit, the failure is reported as"failed the limit".  I would reserve this word for a discussion on the failure modes and characteristics.  I would emphasize here this is from a technical perspective.  Perhaps in a novel you would use it.

Comment: @user116032 The problem is that we haven't yet found a suitable single-word antonym for *exceed* in this context. In technical documentation, [*buffer underrun / underflow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_underrun) is similarly problematic as an English phrase, but it is commonly used as an antonym to a *buffer overrun / overflow*. I'm not completely happy either with *undershoot* for the reasons you've stated; please feel free to post your own alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Receded might be the word you are looking for.

The temperature receded below the lower limit.

Answer (score 1):

For the example sentence, I would use the word ***miss*** to indicate that minimum was not met:

> The temperature *misses* the minimum temperature.

This is in the sense of *fail to perform* or *fail to obtain*.<sup>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miss)</sup>

Comment: With all respect this is most confusing.  .  It doesn't sound like a limit at all.  The phrase sounds like a performance specification.  Have you just failed the product (say a freezer) because it failed to reach a minimum temperature?  "miss" is not what you want.  You might also say here that missing the minimum (if it were a limit) was a success!

Comment: @user116032: In this case, I took *exceed* to mean going beyond a requirement or expectation. So the opposite effect would be a failure to achieve or maintain a requirement or expectation. Please note, I limited my choice to a single word answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the word 'limit' to the end of your existing sentence, it becomes clear that the minimum temperature has been exceeded in the negative direction, and with negative desirability.

> The temperature exceeds the minimum temperature limit.

So I think that *exceeds* is fine in this context. That being said, you could also use 'fallen past' if you want to make the negative direction of the temperature movement explicit.

> The temperature has fallen past the minimum temperature.

It may also be good to make it clear which minimum temperature has been exceeded. For example is it the minimum safe temperature, minimum temperature setting, or minimum operating temperature? I'd quite like to know if I need to evacuate the building, adjust the settings, or just wait for it to warm up so that it works again.

Comment: "Exceeded the lower X (temp, pressure ....) limit" is commonly used.  Within a knowledgeable group (materials testing for example) further elaboration in a report would be bothersome. If it's a consumer bulletin say more.

Comment: Confusing at best.  For the former, I would understand that to mean the temperature is above the minimum limit.  For the latter, it would be much clearer to say "fallen below."

Answer (score 0):

I would ***leave*** it "exceeds the minimum temperature", or perhaps "minimum temperature threshold".

A [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22exceeds%20the%20minimum%20temperature%22) yields well over 100,000 hits with that phrase.

Comment: I feel that this usage leaves some ambiguity. Without context I would assume that "exceeds the minimum temperature" means that the temperature is above the limit.

Comment: @kiddmj Yes, some ambiguity without further context. Unfortunately, that's the nature of English especially within more technical expressions. In a technical context, I would expect "exceeds the minimum temperature" to mean exceeded the specifications for minimum temperature, which is also how I would prefer it to be written. But your context was a bit shallow. ;)